# Make font-awesome icon not affected by other element's semi-opaque background

Tags: css, font-awesome

Here are overlapping blocks. Each one has a semi-opaque background and a `font-awesome` icon inside it.

The goal: make icons not lose their brightness because of overlapping.

I tried applying `z-index` to font-awesome `<i>`, but with no luck: https://jsfiddle.net/zencd/62psvfos/

How it looks now / How I wanted it to be:

[image: example] [image: wanted]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make the icons relatively positioned:

https://jsfiddle.net/Kredit/62psvfos/1/

Relevant changes:

```
i {
    position: relative;
}
```

To improve the existing code, you don't need to supply `z-index` on `.block`, and z-indexes are relative.  Rather than set crazy z-index numbers like `1000`, using `1` accomplishes the same thing (1 layer "higher" than the parent).

```
.block {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    background: rgba(240, 200, 200, 0.8);
    text-align: center;
}

i {
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    outline: 1px dashed black;
}
```

Comment: Good answer. `z-index` doesn't apply to elements without a `position` property (`static` excluded)

Answer (score 2):

set position relative to i elements

```css
body { background: white; }
.block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  background: rgba(240, 200, 200, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 10;
}
.block2 {
  position: relative;
  top: -55px; left: 20px;
}
i {
  z-index: 1000;
  outline: 1px dashed black;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="block">
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-2x"></i>
</div>

<div class="block block2">
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-2x"></i>
</div>
```